# PyMySQL UnicodeEncodeError; python shell successes but cmd fails

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, python, ptvs

I'm new to pymysql module and trying to discover it, I have a simple code:

```
import pymysql

conn=pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1",
                         port=8080,user="root",
                         passwd="mysql",
                         db="world",
                         charset="utf8",
                         use_unicode=True)
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM world.city")

for line in cur:
    print(line)

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I'm using Python Tools for Visual Studio. When i execute the code, it fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\1.5\visualstudio_py_debugger.py", li
ne 1788, in write
    self.old_out.write(value)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 6-7: cha
racter maps to <undefined>
```

Failing line contains city name : `Â´s-Hertogenbosch`

I thought that maybe it's a related problem with cmd output so I've switched to python shell, and my script runs without any error.

So what is the problem I'm facing? 
How can I solve it?

I really want to use Python Tools for Visual Studio, so answers that enable me to use PTVS will be most welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably is that the output encoding of the environment is set to cp437 and the unicode character cannot be converted to that encoding when doing `print(line)` that probably translates to the `self.old_out.write(value)`.

Try to replace the `print()` inside the loop by writing to the file, like:

```
with open('myoutput.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in cur:
        f.write(line)
```

Well, but the cursor does not return a string line. It return a row (I guess tuple) of elements. Because of that you probably have to do something like that:

```
with open('myoutput.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for row in cur:
        f.write(repr(row))
```

This may be enough for a diagnostic purpose. If you need some nicer string, you have to format it in some specific way.

Also, you wrote:

```
                     charset="utf8",
                     use_unicode=True)
```

If the `charset` is used, then `use_unicode=True` can be left out (it is implied by using the `charset`. If I recall correctly, the `charset='utf8'` is not any recognized encoding for Python. You have to use `charset='utf-8'` -- i.e. with dash or underscore between `utf` and `8`. **Correction:** The `utf8` probably works as it is one of the aliases.

**UPDATE** based on comments...

As the output to a file seems to be OK, the problem is related to the capabilities of the window used for the output of the `print` command. As the `cmd` knows only cp437, you have to use or another window (like a Unicode capable window of some GUI), or you have to tell the `cmd` to use another encoding. See the [experience of others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388490/1346705). Basically, you have to tell the console:

```
chcp 65001
```

to change accepted output encoding to UTF-8, or you can use another (non-Unicode) encoding that supports the wanted characters. Also, the console font should be capable to display the characters (i.e. to contain the glyphs, the images of the characters).

Comment: Do you know a way to solve the proble?. Your description is very good and lots of thanks for it but I need a solution.

Comment: When you write the result to the file, does the error also happen?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is the data you're receiving is not in unicode despite the fact that your python script is trying to encode it in Unicode.

I would check for database and table spesific charset & collation settings. utf8 & utf8_general_ci are your friends.

Comment: Applying `encode` means that there is a Unicode string that should be encoded to the stream of bytes in some encoding -- here to cp437. Encoding fails when the conversion of a Unicode character cannot generate the correspondent bytes in the target encoding. This way, I do not think this is the correct answer.

Comment: upon reading the question again I guess pepr is right, it's probably more related with the output encoding.